# Google Analytics Swift - Not Showing the updated Dashboard report

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I've successfully integrated the Google Analytics iOS SDK using cocoapods in my project (Using Swift Language).

1. Added Cocoapods (`pod 'Google/Analytics'`)
2. Generated GoogleService-Info.plist file and added the same to project and final step
3. Initialize the Google Analytics in the AppDelegate.swift

> var configureError:NSError?
>           GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
>   assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services:
>   (configureError)")

4. Added screen view code in viewdidappear

Finally after running the app on the simulator or device, the logs shows the following

> 3.14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:226): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1
>   2016-07-21 13:05:25.265 HelloWorld[4264:206213] INFO: GoogleAnalytics
>   3.14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:529): hit(s) Successfully deleted 2016-07-21
>   13:05:25.266 HelloWorld[4264:206213] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.14
>   -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:237): 1 hit(s) sent

But the same is not reflecting in the Dashboard (Google Analytics)?
[https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web](http://Google%20Analytics%20Dashboard)

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check in real time section, and add some event on clicking button to be able to send report when you want for tests
Are you sure that you add it as an mobile app? If it is working as web it has long delay in report.

Comment: Yeah it's reflects, Kudos @Lukas